# Finding an equation from a gradient vector

Tags: calculus, integration

Find a function $\textbf f$ such that $\nabla \textbf f = 4x^{2} \textbf{i}  - 2y^{2} \textbf{j}$

Normally when approaching this type of situation, I would take the integral of $\ 4x^{2} $ with respect to $\textbf x$ and then differentiate that with respect to $\textbf y$. However, in this case, the answer to the question is $\textbf f = \frac{4x^{2}}{3} - \frac{2y^{2}}{3}$

This makes sense, as the minus sign separates each term, and when taking the derivative there is no y constant when taking the derivative with respect to x and vice versa.

My question is then: how can I tell when this is the case? Am I supposed to use common sense/intuition, or is there a surefire way that I can determine that I need to integrate both terms of the gradient vector and add them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal way to this, is integration of each term with $dx$ and $dy$ respectively. This means, that the common constant that you get during integration on one-variable functions, will be a function this time of $y$ and $x$ respectively. To make it even more clear, the integration of the first term should give you $c_1(y)$ and of the second one $c_2(x)$. This happens because when you are differentiating with respect to one variable, the other is considered a constant and thus vanishes. By doing that, you should get a system that will just lead you to finding the common function by cross-validating the constants. You also have a mistake in your given answer, as the variables should be lifted in the power of $3$ (check that by differentiating and not getting the given gradient).